# Get textToBePresentInElementValue length

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I want to check if my hidden input contains a value, if not just wait until it does.

The reason for this is I know the page has completed loading when the hidden input has an value and I want to use that value.

I have tried the following:
This `textToBePresentInElementValue` gets the value which is great but I need it to wait until it contains a value.

I have tried something like this:
`browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElementValue($('#isearchstring').lenght > 0), 5000);`

But I get an error:
`Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

When my page loads my HTML looks like this : `<input type="hidden" name="searchstring" id="isearchstring" value="">` after a few second it may contain any value `<input type="hidden" name="searchstring" id="isearchstring" value="xxxxx">`

I don't want to use a `browser.sleep();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `getAttribute('value')` to get value of input(no matter it's visible or not)

```
browser.wait(function(){
  return element(by.css('input#isearchstring'))
          .getAttribute('value')
          .then(function(value){
              return value !== '';
          });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This `!===` is not valid operator. Replace it with `!==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for an element to have text, you can write a function for it:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

const isTextPresent = function(elm) {
  const hasText = function() {
    return elm.getText().then(function(elmText) {
      return elmText;
    });
  };
  return EC.and(EC.presenceOf(elementFinder), hasText);
};
```

Then use it:

`browser.wait(isTextPresent(element(by.binding('myvar'))), 5000);`

Comment: For input should use `getAttribute('value')` , rather than `getText()` ,  and `getText()` can't work on hidden element.